# How to plot the output from regular expression?

Tags: python

I am trying to display a set of data from regular expression than plot them.  I use this function to  display my data

```
def loadInfoFrom_Node_Own_Synchronization_signals_List(logFile, signal_sync):
    fsrc = open(logFile, 'r')
    buff = fsrc.read()
    fsrc.close()

    list_info = re.findall(signal_sync, buff)
    print('list_info=  '+str(list_info))
    print('list_info_length=  '+str(len(list_info)))

    dict_node_info = {}
    init_time = None
    for timestamp, id_src_node, Counter in list_info:
        if init_time == None:
            init_time = float(timestamp)

            if id_src_node not in dict_node_info:
                dict_node_info[id_src_node] = {"timestamp": [float(timestamp) - init_time],
                                               'Counter': [int(Counter)]}
            else:
                dict_node_info[id_src_node]["timestamp"].append(float(timestamp) - init_time)
                dict_node_info[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(int(Counter))

    return dict_node_info
```

Set of the regular expression results look like this:

```
list_info=  [('1547226386', '02141592cc00000001', '1'), ('1547226386', '02141592cc00000001', '2'), ('1547226387', '02141592cc00000001', '3'), ('1547226388', '02141592cc00000001', '4'), ('1547226388', '02141592cc00000001', '5'), ('1547226390', '02141592cc00000001', '6'), ('1547226392', '02141592cc00000004', '7'), ('1547226392', '02141592cc00000001', '8'), ('1547226393', '02141592cc00000004', '9'), ('1547226393', '02141592cc00000001', '10'), ('1547226394', '02141592cc00000001', '11'), ('1547226395', '02141592cc00000001', '12'), ('1547226395', '02141592cc00000001', '13'), ('1547226397', '02141592cc00000001', '14'), ('1547226398', '02141592cc00000001', '15'), ('1547226398', '02141592cc00000004', '16'), ('1547226399', '02141592cc00000004', '17'), ('1547226399', '02141592cc00000001', '18'), ('1547226400', '02141592cc00000004', '19')]
```

However, the result of my function returns only this result

```
dict_node_info=  {'02141592cc00000001': {'Counter': [1], 'timestamp': [0.0]}}
```

As consequence, I have an empty plot;the time I need to plot all the output of the regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return dict_node_info` statement is indented too far to the right, making the function return after the first iteration - probably not what you intended. Indent the statement to the left and see if it helps.

Comment: @dina Is the second `if` in parallel with first one in terms of indentation?

Comment: @psychoCoder  thank you very much, it was th mistake. It works correctly now . thank you